# Paperclip is saving files in my root directory on cloud9 - rails, devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

When I upload a file to my app in production a bunch of files are being saved in the root directory of my app.  Is this working as intended?  There are about 8 files one filename for example is `0fadc87e6e0b5ba2f3ba7fe15e4641c920150919-16509-1qkucnc` and they are all named the same except for the last 6 characters.  Here is my user.rb

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "500x500>",
                    :profile => "300x300>", :medium => "300x300>",
                    :thumb => "100x100>", :small => "36x36#",
                    :mini => "26x26#" },
                    :default_url => "/assets/logo.png",
                    :url  => "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar,
                          content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
  validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 5.megabytes
```

I am also using cloud9

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No I ended up switching over to carrierwave.